# Reverse Foreign Key attribute whithin current model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Here a question which I cannot solve after having read various posts. I have two models where one is linked by a foreign key to another one as follow:

```
class Brewery(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

class Beer(models.Model):
    brewery = models.ForeignKey('Brewery', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=True)
```

I would like to store pictures of Beer in a folder which contains the name of the related Brewery. For example, let's say I have the following:

Brewery: id = 1, name = "John_Martin"

Beer: id = 1, brewery = 1, name = "Dominus"

Then I'd like that upload_to points to "John_Martin/Dominus". Is that possible?

Thank you in advance,

OF1418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a callable to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class Beer(models.Model):

    def upload_image_path(self, filename):
        if self.brewery_id is None:
            return …
        return f'{self.brewery.name}/{self.name}/{filename}'

    brewery = models.ForeignKey(
        'Brewery',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=False
    )
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, blank=True)
```

You will need to specify a case however when `self.brewery` is `None`. In that case, you can not use `self.brewery.name`, since there is no `Brewery` for `self.brewery`.